# Description text to appear by cursor pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Probably this is easy, but I cannot get it work:

Using the following `title` attribute, I can display a description text on the defined clickable area:

```
$("#myElement").attr('title', ‘description text’);
```

Is it possible to do the above but instead of the `title` attribute to use the "finger" cursor?

Maybe like as follows:

```
$("myElement").cursor("pointer")
```

Comment: `$("#myElement").css('cursor', 'pointer');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what the title and cursor have to do with each other, but you can change styles in jQuery using:

```
$("myElement").css('cursor', 'pointer')
```

Note that there is an important difference between HTML attributes and styles.  `title` is an attribute and is changed via `.attr`.

Comment: Thank you all for this answer, where exactly the message (‘description text’) is in this code?

Comment: @user203952 You can still keep the `.attr('title'...` why do you want 'description text'?   Maybe I don't understand your question.  Can you show us an example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but I would recommend css over js:

```
#myelement {
    cursor:pointer
}
```

Not sure if you are looking for the most condensed way to do both of these in js, if so then this would be pretty close:

```
$('#myElement').title('text here').css('cursor','pointer');
```

Comment: Thanks, but where to put ‘description text’

Comment: @user203952 You already figured that out, your question has the proper way to do so

Answer (score 1):

```
   $( ".boxClose" ).text( "Title" ).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
   $("#myElement").append($(".boxClose"));

 <style>
 .boxClose{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:10px;
 }
 </style>
```

Use append to add text and change it to cursor .. jquery awesome ..

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to change css properties of the element with javascript, you can use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function in jquery

```
$("myElement").css("cursor", "pointer")
```